# convert php array to js selectpicker array format

Tags: javascript, php, mysqli

This is how I build sql data and send back to ajax call:

```
    (...)
    $sql = "SELECT id_option FROM options WHERE id_win = '{$id_win}'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $rows =  array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
      $rows[] =  $row;
    }

    $data["win_data"] = $rows;
    echo json_encode($data);
```

This is my ajax function to get options for selectpicker from DB:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: ...,
  data: ...,
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data)   {       
    $("#id_win").selectpicker("val", data.win_data);
   // $("#id_win").selectpicker("val", [1,3];
  }
});
```

**data.win_data variable should be: [1,3]**

but if I do:
console.log(JSON.stringify(data.win_data));
I get:

```
[{"0":"1","id_option":"1"},{"0":"3","id_option":"3"}]
```

What is the simplest way to get proper format array for selectpicker?

Comment: tell us print_r($data["win_data"]) please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because `$row` is an array. Look: https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

You have to use like this:

```
    (...)
    $sql = "SELECT id_option FROM options WHERE id_win = '{$id_win}'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $rows =  array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
      $rows[] =  $row['id_option'];
    }

    $data["win_data"] = $rows;
    echo json_encode($data);
```

Answer (score 1):

forget about mysqli and use PDO, it has [everything you need](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#column).

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id_option FROM options WHERE id_win = ?");
$stmt->execute([$id_win]);
$data["win_data"] = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
echo json_encode($data);
```

this code is 2 times **shorter** and 100 times more **secure**